# Tag Friends on Post with Facebook Php SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I develope a platform with php that post on facebook users wall a welcome post. Now i want to tags three friends of the users in the post.

This is my code:

```
 try {     
        $post = $facebook->api("/me/feed","POST",array(

            'message'       =>  "",
            'name'          =>  "",
            'caption'       =>  "",
            'description'   =>  "",
            'link'          =>  "",
            'picture'       =>  "",
        ));
  }
   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $result = $e->getResult();
     }
```

How i can do to tag automatically the friends of users in the post? :-)

P.S. I have all the information about users friends in array(id, name).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tag friends using this end point, this is coupled with the fact that posting on a friend's wall is not allowed. It is only allowed via tagging/mentioning in Open Graph actions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/

Comment: Thank you! But i don't understand something. For example if i have 3 facebook id of friends and i want to use these id to tag automatically this 3 friends in the post of the users, how i can do? 
Some one can give me some code?